# Adding one model to multiple collections

Tags: backbone.js

My application has two collection instances, `allItems` and `someItems`.

I have populated `allItems`, and then have added the first model of `allItems` to `someItems`, like this:

```
 someItems.add(allItems.get(0).toJSON());
```

The problem is this creates a duplicate. If I change an attribute of that model in `someItems`, `allItems` will not be affected.

How can I effectively link the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
someItems.add(allItems.get(0));
```

to add the model and keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

allItems.get(0).toJSON() will create a JSON object which is different from allItems.get(0).

That's why you can't maintain only one object.

Delete .toJSON() and have a try.